# Serialized data on tcpclient needs to state amount?

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0, tcpclient

I have sent data as byte using TcpClient and I wanted to send my own class instead bytes of data.

By bytes of data, what I meant is that I am sending the data converted into bytes like this:

```
using (MemoryStream bufferStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter bufferData = new BinaryWriter(bufferStream))
    {
        // Simple PONG Action
        bufferData.Write((byte)10);
    }

    _logger.Info("Received PING request, Sending PONG");
    return bufferStream.ToArray();
}
```

And instead I would like to send it like this, without having to declare its size or w/e

```
public class MyCommunicationData
{
    public ActionType Action { get; set; }
    public Profile User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Normally, when I send my data as bytes the first 5 bytes I use to indicate the action and the message size.

But if I migrate to serialize all the data as a single class, do I still need to send what action and size it is or using serialized messages the client and server would know what to read etc or is there a way to do so I can send it without having to specify things out of the serialization object ?

Not sure if this matters here, I am using `AsyncCallback` to read and write to the network stream:

```
_networkStream = _client.tcpClient.GetStream();
_callbackRead = new AsyncCallback(_OnReadComplete);
_callbackWrite = new AsyncCallback(_OnWriteComplete);
```

Let me know if you need me to post any other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a text based serializer(for ex, Json), you can utilize StreamReader's `ReadLine` and StreamWriter's `WriteLine` (created from tcpClient.GetStream).

Your code would be something like

```
 writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commData))
```

and to get the data on the other end

```
var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCommunicationData>(reader.ReadLine())
```

--EDIT--

```
//**Server**
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
    var writer = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
    while (true)
    {
        var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCommunicationData>(reader.ReadLine());
        //do work with obj 
        //write response to client
        writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commData));
    }
}, 
TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Comment: I was considering using JSON, but using that will the client/server know the size or how to read it to the end ? Thats my main concern.

Comment: @Guapo No, as in my example. you don't write anything to stream other than the serialized data. `EndOfLine` char is used  between serialized data and handled by ReadLine. You just read lines from network and deserialize.

Comment: So any line break within the class data I would have to convert to something else prior sending it to avoid it breaking before the end of the class ? or it does not matter as a line break doesn't send the EOF ?

Comment: No, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` handles this for you.

Comment: Ah cool, I will give it a try now. Are there other options to this like the common c# serialization in regards knowing the data size etc ?

Comment: My bad, by common I mean methods within .net4

Comment: You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) But I prefer [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) as in my answer.

Comment: Yes I prefer Json.Net too but I meant like xml serialization, or other type of serialization that would work

Comment: Xml can be problematic since it can contain NewLine chars. You should have to escape them after serialization as you said.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot ;) I will go try this and see how it goes.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, your method seems to work pretty well for me at least so far, however, in your code there is a small error the `()` before `(reader.ReadLine())`, also, it seems the `reader.ReadLine()` cannot be used directly so I have to have it read prior to using it or it will be blocked on the Deserialization method forever to make sure the line is not null or empty.

Comment: @Guapo The whole idea is that it should be blocked on readline and continue to work when a complete json is available. You can use it in a thread in a infinite loop.

Comment: That was such a silly mistake of my part, I was using UTF8 on the streams which does not seems to have the EOF which was failing to read the data I believe. Really appreciate for the update :)