# Passing and Receiving complex objects in C# Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to asynchronously receive complex object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452765/how-to-asynchronously-receive-complex-object-in-c)

My complex object is of type IOrderedQueryable
It has 4 attributes, all of type List

I'm sending my object using asynchronous socket through this:

```
        private void SendDatabaseObj(Socket handler, IOrderedQueryable<BuildHistory1> buildHistoryQueryResult)
        {
            byte[] byteData = ObjectToByteArray(buildHistoryQueryResult);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }
```

ObjectToByteArray() function (Serializing the object before sending):

```
        private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

I'm receiving the object I sent through this:

```
        private void ReceiveCallback_onQuery(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There might be more data, so store the data received so far. But how to store?

                    // Get the rest of the data.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback_onQuery), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                    if (dataReceived > 1)
                    {
                        //Use the deserializing function here to retrieve the object to its normal form
                    }
                    // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                    receiveDoneQuery.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

My de-serializing function:

```
        private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrayBytes)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            ms.Write(arrayBytes, 0, arrayBytes.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Object obj = (Object)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return obj;
        }
```

Now my question is in the receiving function "ReceiveCallback_onQuery()". If there are more data to be received, how to store previously received data?

EDIT:
I am aware of doing the code below but is there other ways of just storing the data received in a byte[] variable so I could convert them back to IOrderedQueryable

```
state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
```

Comment: Have you considered using a ready-made solution like WCF rather than inventing your own network protocol?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: WCF is a communication framework which uses the SOAP protocol to execute remote procedures on a server and pass complex data objects.  SOAP is XML based, so it can easily handle complex data types.  If that's the kind of thing you are doing, creating a WCF service or a simple asmx web service would be much easier than what you are doing.  For instance, you could make a WCF service with a method like `public void Submit(IOrderedQueryable<BuildHistory1> buildHistoryQueryResult)`, and then just call that method on the service from the client application.

Answer (score 0):

When streaming data, such as with sockets, you have to have, built-in to your protocol, some way to know where the beginning and ending of each message is in the data.  This is handled automatically by tools for standard protocols (such as WCF for SOAP), but if you are going to design your own protocol, you'll need to implement it yourself.  The simplest method would be to add a known delimiter character or string between each message, but then you need to be careful that the delimiter never appears within a message's data.  Another alternative would be to send the length of the message in a message header, or to simply use fixed-length messages.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a `IQueryable` over the network. You can't use the querying features on the other side. Instead create a class which represents a request (i.e. contains information about which items to receive) and a response (an object which contains an array of matching objects).

If you do not want to take care of the networking layer by yourself and want's a more lightweight approach than WCF you can use my Griffin.Networking library.

I've just uploaded a video that demonstrates how to create a simple chat client/server in 20 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjJOaV2y1Lo

Sample code: https://github.com/jgauffin/Samples/tree/master/Griffin.Networking/ChatServerClient