# Sorting through byte arrays

Tags: c#, sorting, arrays

My program sends data from one application to another in a byte array. I want to pull sections of the data out to store in different variables. for instance the first [7] in the byte array hold the symbol data, the next section is a number which i don't know the length of because it will vary with each msg it sends. Before i send the data i break it up with commas between each section of data i want. My issue is setting up a loop that will stop at the commas so i can add the data into another variable. If this makes sense please any ideas will help. Thanks.

Comment: have you considered other data formats, as JSON or XML? If you hold control over both applications, you should choose between one of these wide spread data interchange formats.

Comment: Do you have a bit of code you can show where you `break it up with commas between each section of data`. It's hard to picture what you mean in the context of a byte array. Maybe this isn't the ideal structure for passing your data around?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to split the array, not sort it.  I recommend altering the title accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721710/serialized-data-on-tcpclient-needs-to-state-amount

Comment: the data being put into the byte array is 

string order = f.symbol.ToString() + "," + f.count.ToString();

Then stored into a byte array, i want my for loop to stop at the comma take that data from the previous array subids and store it into another value so i can use it. still too vague?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what encoding you have, since comma is not always the same byte value in different encoding schemes.  Also if you want efficiency, you can try to parse the byte array as a byte array, but this is easier.  Also, you could create a class on both ends that has the properties you need and is [Serializable].

If for whatever reason you don't want to do that then you can easily parse the byte array like this:

```
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string s = encoding.GetString(byteArray);
string[] values = s.Split(new char[] {','});

//then do something with the values
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is just complicated to handle as a byte array, as it's really encoded text. Just decode it (using the encoding that you used to turn it into a byte array) and split it:

```
string[] parts = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Split(',');
```

Now ou can get each part and parse them:

```
int symbol = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
int count = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend defining an object model that represents the data that you need to send, and then using some serialization framework to convert this to/from a byte array.

See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

Another topic which may be interesting for you is data contracts in .Net.