# C# TCP Trying to send values as chars

Tags: c#, tcp

I have some int values that all is within the 0-65535 range (16 bit). I need to transfer these across TCP connection, so I thought that converting these values to chars, and sending the chars, then decode the chars on the other end would fit the requirement.

First I create a string (the message) then I convert the numbers to chars and add them at the end of the message

```
        String unencodedMessage = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 513; i++)
        {
            unencodedMessage += (char)i;
        }
```

I then story this message along with a TcpClient to use (GetMessage() and GetClient(). Converts the text as required (copy paste from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) verify that the TcpClient still appear to be valid (but as this is not guarantied I use the try).

```
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(internalMessages[i].GetMessage());
                TcpClient tmpClient = internalMessages[i].GetClient();
                if (tmpClient.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        NetworkStream stream = internalMessages[i].GetClient().GetStream();
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
```

On the other end I receive the message and revert it back to a string like this.

```
            while (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

                numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                internalMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            }
```

Once converted back I loop through the values and print them to verify everything is ok (note the String that is decoded is in index 1, of the list of strings), the 2nd. index should get me the chars back, and by converting those to ints I should get the 0-65535, I story these as text in a new string separated by : and write them in 1 go.

```
        public void UnencodeData(List<String> command)
        {
            String msg = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < command[1].Count();i++)
            {
                msg += ((int)command[1][i]) + ":";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
```

I would expect a countup from 1:2:3: ... 512:513:, instead I get

> Blockquote
>   0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:63:

Which is not quite what I expected, seems everything was going well until I got past the 7th bit of value.

---

What did I do wrong? what would have been a smarter approach to try to ship the values (expected range 0-10000). I could send the value as plain text, I just feel it is a waste.

As pointed out by several of the answers. The issue is the two lines I use here, with the Encoding.ASCII that cause the issue, and a more appropriate way instead of going over the Chars would be to convert the numbers directly to the Byte[] but I have chosen to not do so, as the write/read I use in my tool currently uses Strings as input. But that is beside the issue at hand, namely why the data did not match on the other end, so core issue Encoding.ASCII from official documentation gave the issue.

```
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(internalMessages[i].GetMessage());

internalMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
```

---

Working lines.

```
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(internalMessages[i].GetMessage());

internalMessage += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: Why do you encode in the first place?  why not just send raw bits?  Note you will need to understand the concept of `network byte order`

Comment: @PeterM As said copy pasted code as was presented on the MSDN article, and wanted to reuse what I already setup. So to be honest. I have no clue why I am encoding.

Comment: @Tach After looking at that link I'd suggest that you do more research on sending data across TCP links.  That is the sort of code that should be taken out and shot, and then burned into ashes, and the ashes scattered in multiple locations. (well maybe it is suitable for sending text messages)

Comment: @PeterM Comforting to know the official guide is of high quality. Unless you are refering to my code, in which case I have to admit, I am a novice, and I just want to be able to send a String from A to B and have it decoded. How its done not too important. String goes in, same String goes out on the other end ;)

Comment: @Taoh I think you can use some serializers to send your byte array(or any kind of data) like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721710/serialized-data-on-tcpclient-needs-to-state-amount)

Comment: @L.B I do not plan on using serializers for what I am trying to send here. I am considering it plain text in terms of abstraction layer, and I (thought I) had a clear plan of how to handle it. Take the string, replace all '*' with '**', and separate message with '* ', so I could keep the sender and receiver decoupled and possible to write without forcing a specific language. I might completely misunderstand serializers, but to me it is a language specific way to turn an object to a string and send it and restore it within the same language on the other end. it is not what I am looking for here

Comment: `I might completely misunderstand serializers` you are right you misunderstand completely. xml and json(as in my previous link) are language agnostic. This is why they are used for data passing between different platforms.(see for example twitter,facebook, google APIs)

Comment: @L.B Do you have a link to where I can read up on some good basic knowledge of what it is and how it works. Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the [`ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) encoding, in which:

> ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F.

In fact, probably none of other encodings will suit your needs (probably, as it's hard to guess what are your needs) - all of the use some kind of fall-back characters if they encounter a byte they can't encode, and you seem to just put some random bytes into a string.

The simplest solution seems to use a [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You may also consider [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding if you really want strings.

So, if you want to send text you have in strings just use: `data = Encoding.UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(unencodedMessage);` (or `UTF16` as you noted yourself). Otherwise, if you want to send some arbitrary values:

```
data = unencodedMessage.SelectMany(c => BitConverter.GetBytes(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Taoh Well, I always try to force the asker to do as much effort on their own as possible. In the long run, this is what counts - improved research skill :) Possibly it was too much in this case, I'll try better next time, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not just convert your short values to byte arrays using something like BitConverter?

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(...)
```

And then on the receiving end

```
ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(...)
```

Or am I missing something?